Clustering a Grid into segments of equal length
I have a grid with many interconnections. The grid consists of edges of different length. I would like to cluster this grid into segments of similar length. The edges which are summarized in a cluster have to be connected. I would like to give a maximum cluster length, so I can control, how many clusters are created. Objective should be to create as few clusters as possible.
What algorithms might be useful for this?
So far I created a networkX graph and asked chatgpt for some ideas, without great success.
Extract of the grid with nodes between edge features

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

I found a good solution. I cluster the grid by an algorithm and iteratively cluster again those clusters which still have a total length larger than my threshold. I I got best results with the greedy_modularity_community algorithm.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

Please post the solution with a code snippet
